# Proving $\vdash (\exists x)(A\rightarrow(\forall x)A)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

How does one prove $\vdash (\exists x)(A\rightarrow(\forall x)A)$?

I can think of using duality: $\vdash(\exists x)(A\wedge B) \equiv A\wedge (\exists x) B$

However, I'm not too sure how to formally go about it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is $A$ a property of $x$ or is it independent? If it is independent, then it is essentially $A\to A$.

Comment: How you formally go about it is a function of what formal system you are using, so we would need to know more about that to answer. (Also I don't think that axiom is or should be called duality. Also it is only valid if $x$ is not free in $A$.) Anyhow, this may help for the intuition and for searching the site for duplicates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox

Answer (score 0):

The negation is
$\forall x (A \wedge \neg \forall x A)$
iff
$\forall x A \wedge \forall x \neg \forall x A)$
iff
$\forall x A \wedge \neg \forall x A)$
which is clearly false.

Comment: It's not *that* clearly false as both this and the original statement rely on the assumption of a non-empty domain. This assumption isn't always made that explicit and, of course, it need not be made, though it usually is in traditional accounts.

Comment: Proof from the axioms, not that  satisfying stuff of valid models.. @DerekElkins

Comment: There are clearly things in the rules/axioms that *imply* that the domain is non-empty in traditional accounts. This can be explicit, e.g. $\exists x.\top$, but more often it is implicit, e.g. in the rules for "null quantification" which state $A$ entails $\exists x.A$ when $x$ is not free in $A$. If we set $A$ to $\top$, which certainly doesn't contain $x$ free, we get $\top$ entails $\exists x.\top$. A more careful accounting of the rules will not have this entailment. You will need these "bad" cases of null quantification (or something equivalent) to prove this statement.

Comment: @DerekElkins.  See edit.   An axiomatic proof without that superfluous domain thing.  The problem is about |-, not about |=.

Comment: The second step uses null quantification as I said would be necessary. If you write the rules of inference carefully, that step isn't one of the rules of inference. That we usually *do* allow this rule of inference *corresponds to* the semantic fact that we usually require domains to be non-empty. (We have soundness and completeness.) If you allow empty domains, then the rule is *not* sound. If the domain is empty, then $\forall x.P(x)$ for *any* $P(x)$ is vacuously true. Choose $A=\bot$ in the original formula and you immediately get $\exists x.\top$.